# LinearLayout won't display everything

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, android-linearlayout

My problem might seems easy, but I really can't resolve it. At some point, my code displays a bunch of images (`ImageView`) in a `LinearLayout`, inside an `AlertDialog`.
The problem is that not everything is displayed.

Here's my code :

```
public  LinearLayout createLayout(String text) {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this.c);

    int res;
    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); ++i) {
        res = this.c.getResources().getIdentifier("pigpen_" + Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i)), "drawable", this.c.getPackageName());
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this.c);
        iv.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
        iv.setImageResource(res);
        ll.addView(iv);
    }
    return ll;
}
```

And the code for the DialogAlert :

```
protected ResultDialog(final Context context, CharSequence title, LinearLayout ll) {
    super(context);

    ll.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);

    this.setView(ll);
    this.setTitle(title);
}
```

[image]

And as you can see, the result is not good. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this.c); 
    ArrayList<Integer> alImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); ++i) {
        cur = text.charAt(i);
        pos = this.getCharAlphabetPosition(cur);
        if(pos > 0 && pos < alphabetId.length) {
            res = alphabetId[pos];
            alImages.add(res);
        }
    }
    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.c, alImages));
    gv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    gv.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
    gv.setColumnWidth(25);

    ll.addView(gv);
}
```

Et ma classe ImageAdapter :
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private Context c;
    private ArrayList alImages;

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Integer> alImages) {
    this.c = c;
    this.alImages = alImages;
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.alImages.size();
}

public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return this.alImages.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(this.c);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(25, 25));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(this.getItem(position));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `LinearLayout` does not have any dimensions. Width and height are 0. So everything works perfectly.

You are lacking a call to [setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), that's all.

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your helps. I've tried your solution, but nothing change. I've also tried to put a minimumHeight : the layout is the good height, but the images are still not all displayed. The perfect ehavior would be to have some kind of carriage return each 9 images. Do you think using a RelativeLayout would work better ?

Comment: You probably search for `GridView`.

Comment: I've used a TableLayout, with a new tableRow every 10 images. I'm just concern about the way it will behave on larger screen.

Comment: @Passeur TableLayout is also a working choice where I still recommend using a GridLayout - Higher performance and way more flexibility!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your LinearLayout with an HorizontalScrollView. That way you can add a lot of images and scroll to view them all.